# Why do I get an incompatible types when assigning to type 'uint16_t ' error?

Tags: c, incompatibletypeerror

I am getting a `incompatible types when assigning to type 'uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from type 'ble_uuid_t {aka struct <anonymous>}` in this piece of code

```
ble_uuid_t    ble_uuid;

ble_uuid.uuid = m_adv_uuid[0];
```

where I have defined `m_adv_uuid` as

```
#define AMT_SERVICE_UUID             0x2001
#define AMTS_CHAR_UUID               0x20
#define AMT_RCV_BYTES_CNT_CHAR_UUID  0x2003

ble_uuid_t m_adv_uuid[] = {AMT_SERVICE_UUID, AMTS_CHAR_UUID};
```

being `ble_uuid_t` defined as

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t    uuid; 
  uint8_t     type; 
} ble_uuid_t;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually two problems:

1. you are initializing array of structs, which must be done like this:

   ```
   ble_uuid_t m_adv_uuid[] = { { AMT_SERVICE_UUID, AMTS_CHAR_UUID } };
   ```
2. and then you are accessing struct instead of its member `uuid`. Your assignment should look like this:

   ```
   ble_uuid.uuid = m_adv_uuid[0].uuid;
   ```

Or, of course, if you don't want `m_adv_uuid` to be an array of `ble_uuid_t`, it's enough to just remove `[]` in declaration of `m_adv_uuid` and rest of your code will work:

```
ble_uuid_t m_adv_uuid = {AMT_SERVICE_UUID, AMTS_CHAR_UUID};
```

Answer (score 1):

you're defining an array of your structures and try to initialize it. But you're passing data for 1 structure only.

The compiler thinks you're trying to initialize 2 `ble_uuid_t` structs, with incompatible types.

That would work for 1 struct:

```
ble_uuid_t m_adv_uuid = {AMT_SERVICE_UUID, AMTS_CHAR_UUID};
```

and to initialize 2 structs you could do:

```
ble_uuid_t m_adv_uuid[] = {{AMT_SERVICE_UUID, AMTS_CHAR_UUID},{AMT_SERVICE_UUID, AMTS_CHAR_UUID}};
```